# Import the all tables from RDBMS using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to import data from testing mysql database to hadoop using sqoop. But in some tables having primary and some tables does not have primary key.

```
$sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101/mysql -username test -P --warehouse-dir /home/user_all_tables
```

> 17/08/01 22:46:54 ERROR tool.ImportAllTablesTool: Error during import:
>   No primary key could be found for table general_log. Please specify
>   one with --split-by or perform a sequential import with '-m 1'.

Kindly suggest me how to use split by in sqoop command line.

Answer (score 1):

For the `import-all-tables` tool to be useful, the following conditions must be met:

- Each table must have a single-column primary key.
- You must intend to import all columns of each table.
- You must not intend to use non-default splitting column, nor impose any conditions via a WHERE clause.

Default option doesn't fit with the non primary key table therefore it is not working. Here I will suggests to use `-m 1` option to strict the import with one mapper only.

Sqoop command:

```
import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101/mysql -username test \ 
-P --warehouse-dir /home/user_all_tables -m 1
```

Comment: Thank You Sandeep

Comment: Instead of setting -m 1 single mapper you can try another option. use the --spilt-by and specify the column with unique values.

Comment: @kumsgs - yes! but in that case he has to investigate all non primary key tables to find out the integer column to specify with `--split-by`

Comment: and then individual Sqoop command is required for all non primary key table because integer column could be different for tables.